# PHP - Add a task to an opportunity

Tags: api, opportunity, php

Using the Saleforces PHP library, how would I go about creating a 'New task' under an opportunity.

This is what I have going right now.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->WhatId = "Opportunity"; // Not sure if this is correct
$obj->AccountId = "XXXXXX"; // The opportunity ID?
$obj->Subject = "Subject";
$obj->Description = "This is a description";
$obj->Status = "In Progress";
$obj->Priority = "Normal";
$obj->Status = "Completed";
$sfcon->create([$obj], 'Task');
```

It doesn't cause any errors, but it also isn't creating a new task under my opportunity. Am I going in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem after being stuck for a while. I had to put my opportunity ID into the **WhatID** field.

```
$obj->WhatID = "Opp ID";
```